# Is there a way for me to create a data validation rule that will only allow entries based on a given date?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a data validation rule that will only accept 0 in cell E6 if the date E5 is greater than the end of the month of the date I entered in B3. Is this possible?

Here's my [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YCpC1o1BR1tvsvdNhsyCtaPM9S7E5F-TnjsJCK51UKk/edit?usp=sharing).

I want that if the date in E5 is before or falls on the day of the end of the month of the date I entered in B3, I'll be able to enter any number aside from 0. I tried creating a custom formula but it did not work. Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom formula for a validation rule:

```cpp
=if(eomonth($B$3,0)>=C5, true, if(C6=0, true, false))
```

Where:

- `$B$3` is the reference date.
- `C5` is the date that must be on or before end of month of `$B$3`.
- `C6` is the input cell.

This formula assumes that the top-left cell of the range you apply the validation rule is `C5`.

Answer (score 0):

***Data validation rule***

*Apply to range*: `C6:F6`

*Custom formula is*:

```
=if(C5>eomonth($B$3,),0,filter(C6,C6<>0))=C6
```

[image]